# I am trying to use rowEvents to trigger an action in react-bootstrap-table-2 but 'this' in the onClick is undefined. Any ideas?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, this, react-bootstrap-table

Here is the codeblock:

```
const expandRow = {
    renderer: row => (
        <div>
            <BootstrapTable
                keyField='id'
                data={ row.data }
                columns={ columns1 }
            />
        </div>
    )
};

export default class MyPage extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.actions.fetchData().  // fetches in this.props.data
    }

    rowEvents = {
        onClick: (e, row, rowIndex) => {
            this.props.actions.fetchHistory(row.Id).   /* this is undefined */
        }
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <BootstrapTable
                keyField='Id'
                data={ this.props.data }
                columns={ columns }
                striped
                rowEvents={ this.rowEvents }
                expandRow={ expandRow }
            />
        )
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is for each row clicked, I want to fetch data by triggering an action. I might be wrong about understanding the context of 'this' here. Any ideas?

Comment: Which package/version you're using for react bootstrap table?

Comment: [react-bootstrap-table-next](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/?selectedKind=Work%20on%20Rows&selectedStory=Row%20Event&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel)

Comment: Its working fine for me. Which version you're using?

Comment: "react-bootstrap-table-next": "2.1.0",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out a way to fix the 'this' context issue. Implementing the `rowEvents` in a slightly different way as below. I am still not quite sure why I ran into such a context issue.

```
let rowEvents = () => {
    return{
    onClick: rowOnClick
    }
}
async function rowOnClick(e, row, rowIndex) {
    await this.props.actions.fetchLogHistory(row.orchestratorId)
}

and bind rowOnClick to this in the constructor:
this.rowOnClick = this.rowOnClick.bind(this)
```

However, although I used async/await to trigger the action, I ran into another issue where the expanded row (inner) bootstrap table loaded before the action got reduced and it had no data in the props. What I am attempting now is to use another `Component` rendered in expanded row, and in it, I'll have the inner bootstrap table, whose `componenDidMount` will fetch the data.

Answer (score 4):

rowEvents is not a function but a constant, try to define it with const

```
const rowEvents = {
        onClick: (e, row, rowIndex) => {
            this.props.actions.fetchHistory(row.Id).   /* this is undefined */
        }
    }
```

Comment: Khotu che topa su be

Comment: topesh to shu aave? 